# how to make the text to be displayed in rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

i want to display the text in rows how can i do this here is the code which does that

```
 text=messages+"";
```

Comment: Seems, you don't write any data into Excel sheet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change this line of code:

```
szText = szText + szMessage + "\r<br>";
```

To this:

```
szText += szMessage;
```

Comment: So is it printing the error message the way you wanted to now?

Comment: To set the colour you can try surrounding the string in something like `<div style='color:red;'>` If you don't come right you can ask a new question on stackoverflow and someone will assist you